# Is it hibernate bug?

Tags: java, hibernate

I write

```
    String sql = "select candidate_skill.candidate_id from candidate_skill " +
            "inner join skill on  skill.id = candidate_skill.skill_id  " +
            "where skill_id in (:skillIdList) group by candidate_skill.candidate_id " +
            "Having count(candidate_skill.candidate_id) = (select count(*) from skill where skill.id in (:skillIdList) )";
    sql = sql.replace(":skillIdList", generateSkillIdList(skills));
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    List<Candidate> candidates = query.list();
```

It works good

second situation:

```
    String sql = "select candidate_skill.candidate_id from candidate_skill " +
            "inner join skill on  skill.id = candidate_skill.skill_id  " +
            "where skill_id in :skillIdList group by candidate_skill.candidate_id " +
            "Having count(candidate_skill.candidate_id) = (select count(*) from skill where skill.id in :skillIdList )";
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setParameterList("skillIdList", skills);
    List<Candidate> candidates = query.list()
```

log:

```
Hibernate: select candidate_skill.candidate_id from candidate_skill inner join skill on  skill.id = candidate_skill.skill_id  where skill_id in (?, ?) group by candidate_skill.candidate_id Having count(candidate_skill.candidate_id) = (select count(*) from skill where skill.id in ?, ? )
```

it doesn't works

and third:

```
String sql = "select candidate_skill.candidate_id from candidate_skill " +
                "inner join skill on  skill.id = candidate_skill.skill_id  " +
                "where skill_id in :skillIdList group by candidate_skill.candidate_id " +
                "Having count(candidate_skill.candidate_id) = (select count(*) from skill where skill.id in (:skillIdList) )";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).setParameterList("skillIdList", skills);
        List<Candidate> candidates = query.list();
```

log:

```
Hibernate: select candidate_skill.candidate_id from candidate_skill inner join skill on  skill.id = candidate_skill.skill_id  where skill_id in (?, ?) group by candidate_skill.candidate_id Having count(candidate_skill.candidate_id) = (select count(*) from skill where skill.id in (?, ?) )
```

it works good

P.S. Pay attention to the Brackets around `:skillIdList`

if I use setParameterList("argument",value) and argument in query 2 times, then first time hibernate substitutes brackets and in second - none

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: exception of mssql server. It return me it on my native language.

Comment: It is non informational exception message

Comment: Rule of thumb: When you ask "I'm trying to do this very basic thing, it doesn't work. Is it a bug in this established and popular language/framework/library?" the answer is almost invariably "no".

Comment: about incorrect sql syntax

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `IN` requires the brackets.

As of why the 3rd example is working, two guesses:

- hibernate has a functionality to automatically append missing brackets, but somehow this doesn't extend to subqueries
- the sql server executes the sub-select first, and then the other query becomes redundant with the parameters you've passed, and so is not executed.

Comment: I agree, but I'm passing list for hibernate  - it itself can substitute parenthesis if necessary. No?

Comment: hm, my initial version seems to be correct then, I re-added  it :)